# TextView transparency over VideoView

Tags: textview, transparency, android-videoview, alpha

I am writing an App which runs on Android 4.0.3 which uses video out via HDMI for a display.

I had a tinted, transparent TextView working on top of a VideoView, but over a series of seemingly unrelated changes I have broken it and cannot get it working again.

I was using the SetBackgroundColor, i.e.,

```
myTextView.setBackgroundColor( Color.argb ( 128, 128, 0, 0 ) );
```

The symptom is the TextView displays a solid background color (RGB 128,0,0) and no transparency.  If I set the alpha to between 0, the background becomes fully transparent but I can still make out the color of the background behind the VideoView on the outline of the text inside the TextView.  When I set the alpha anything higher like 10 for example, the background becomes a solid color, i.e., the example above would become RGB(128,0,0).

I have fiddled with many things such as `setAlpha(float)`, `setBackgroundColor(Color)`, dynamically creating the Views in different orders, creating and ordering views in XML , `bringToFront()`, `getBackground().setAlpha( int )`, `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` all to no further success.

I built another simple app with everything removed to try and work out what was happening, but no success.

**XML layout**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/frame"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/videoScreen"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
   </VideoView>  
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textScreen"
       android:layout_width="300sp"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="#80800000"
       android:text="@string/hello_world" 
       android:lines="400" >    
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Simple videoView**

```
final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController( getWindow().getContext() );
videoView = ( VideoView )findViewById( R.id.videoScreen );
mediaController.setAnchorView( videoView );
videoView.setMediaController( mediaController );        
videoView.setVideoPath( "/mnt/extsd/test-movie.mov" );
videoView.start();
```

If I have understood correctly, this should produce a red tinted, semi-transparent TextView over a running VideoView, but I cannot seem to make it work.

If I remove the VideoView and place an ImageView with a picture, the transparency and background color tinting **does** work.  Im suspecting something unusual about TextView over VideoView.

Does anyone have any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?  or something to check?

Is there something obvious I am missing?

A short working example of a TextView using a background color of Color.*argb*( 128, 128, 0, 0 ) over a VideoView would be appreciated if anyone has one.